# Which UL standard(s) holds the specifications of all UL AWM styles of cabling?

Tags: wiring, wire, standard, ul

Which UL standard documents the specifications of all UL AWM styles of cabling, detailing their construction, conductor sizes, insulation, etc. ?

In my research, I was directed to UL Standard 758 *Appliance Wiring Materials*, but it does not contain the specifications of each individual styles.
I also found https://iq.ul.com/awm/ which is supposed to be a library of the styles, but the page doesn't load for me and throws an error.

From the UL.com site, I went into `Resources` / `UL Standards` which brought me to
https://www.shopulstandards.com. Once there, searching for 20276 or 2725 (or UL20276 or UL2725) brings up nothing.

Comment: Page 14 & beyond    https://legacy-uploads.ul.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/WC_MG.pdf

Comment: @KyleB thanks, this document provides *some* insights and is useful, but it's not a complete spec.

Comment: Without knowing for absolute certain, I would propose that to access a 'global knowledgebase' is going to cost $$$.   UL is a for-profit company.  They don't give away their standards, you have to pay to get them.  And they are very much copyrighted (i.e. if you find them for download, it's probably not legal).   Have you tried sending UL an email???   Worst they can do is ignore you and they might even be helpful!

Comment: @KyleB well, I am familiar with quite a few standardization bodies, their websites and their business practices. I bought quite a few standards myself. Typically you search for a standard or spec, get to see the exert and table of contents and you can then buy the full thing. In UL's case, one can't even find an individual style spec by typing the number in their search. Neither can you find a unique, broader spec that would encompass all the AWM styles, which would actually make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found some sources of UL official information. They're quite hidden in UL's website, which ain't great.

First you have to go to

`UL.com` / `Resources`  / `Tools, Apps and Databases`

1. UL iQ Databases

Find the big tile named `UL iQ Databases` . From that page :

> Certified materials are added to the UL iQ® databases on a daily
> basis, making this information immediately available to thousands of
> designers, engineers and suppliers. Leveraging this extensive
> collection of data, UL’s iQ databases allows users to find, verify and
> specify certified material and components that meet certain safety and
> performance requirements.
>
> Similar to the Online Certifications Directory (Product iQ), many
> end-product manufacturers use this database to verify the
> certification information of the components they intend to use in
> their end-product applications. Through more than 20 possible
> parametric search criteria, users can additionally identify multiple
> components and suppliers who have UL Recognition with ratings that
> meet the safety criteria of a specific end-product application.
>
> UL’s iQ is made up of the following 12 databases:
>
> ```
> Appliance wiring material (AWM)
> Electrical insulation systems (EIS) 
> Fuses
> Labels
> Plastics
> Printed wiring boards (PWB)
> Sign components
> Solid state lighting
> Surge protective devices
> Switches
> Certified water products
> Wire and cable
> ```

Sadly, at this time (2021-03-08), the site throws an error when I click "Learn more" which I'm guessing is the way to access the actual database : "Due to a system outage, the UL iQ Database is unavailable".

2. UL Product iQ

Then, if you go back to `Tools, Apps and Databases`  and click on the other big tile, named `UL Product IQ`

> UL Product iQ™ combines UL Safety Certification information trusted
> around the globe with the intuitive design and functionality of a
> modern search engine. This intuitive search tool allows you to quickly
> locate the product or component that will meet your needs. If you
> don’t have an exact certification number, no worries. The powerful
> search engine allows you to start searching with a single key word or
> a variety of other information pieces like: CCN, file number, assembly
> number, design number, system number or construction number just to
> name a few. Refining search results with filters makes it easy to also
> identify alternate solutions.
>
> Product iQ has the data you can trust whether you’re verifying the UL
> certification of a product or component, locating UL guide information
> or searching for alternative products. This powerful database features
> robust and intuitive search features, advanced search and filtering
> options and access to UL guide information.
>
> Many engineers, product developers, architects and other professionals
> upgrade their accounts to enjoy the ability to:
>
> ```
> Access printable UL certification letters
> Save regularly used, custom and complex queries 
> Leverage custom tagging and grouping of content
> Receive automatic notification of updates to a search or file
> ```

So when you click on the link "Start exploring Product iQ today", it finally brings you to https://productiq.ulprospector.com . This one lists all qualified vendor products built as per the styles. Not exactly what I'm looking for, but it's a start.